# mail() in foreach loop

Tags: php, email

mail() is used to send email to users in the array provided to foreach loop. I want to put limit to the number of emails sent per hour. Besides, I need to keep track of how many emails sent and not sent ( with AJAX possibly ).

Is there I can put pause between the time each email is sent, other than sleep()? Coz it stops the whole script and I will not be able to track the number of emails being sent.

Code is simple:

```
foreach ($user_emails as $user_email) {
    if(mail( $user_email, $subject, $model->message, $headers))
    {
        echo "sent </br>";

    }
}
```

Advice on good library would also be great! Thanks :)

Comment: Put the information in a database, and run an hourly cron job that takes some items out of the database and mails them.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for your answer but I am not aware of how to use cron job. That's why, let me ask you one more question: this whole form is going to be in admin page, admin or adminstrator(or anybody else) goes there, chooses the group of people, writes the message, and sends them, activating my cron job script. I will certainly have a read on cron jobs but before I do I wanted to make sure this is the right tool coz I am kinda short of time. So, the question is, is this going to be as user-friendly as I described above?

Comment: The problem is you can't do what you want just in the web page by itself. The browser is waiting for the script to finish, and if it's going to put delays in then that will fail.

Comment: @Barmar Unless performed through ajax. Server can also be configured to keep running the script, even though the client cancelled the request (so user can navigate away from the call and keep the script running). However, there's probably server timeouts and php timeouts that would need to be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the mails you want to send in the database, and execute a cronjob/crontab to open a PHP file which reads from the database and send an x amount of emails. The cronjob can be configured to run every minute, half an hour, hour, etc, as per your requirement. In terms of load it is probably better to run the cronjob more often and send smaller amount of emails per execution, instead of running the cronjob less often and sending more mails at the same time.

Of course, don't forget to remove the email record (or mark it as sent) from the db after running the mail command for that record, so that it won't get sent twice.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I am not aware of how to use cron job. That's why, let me ask you one more question: this whole form is going to be in admin page, admin or adminstrator(or anybody else) goes there, chooses the group of people, writes the message, and sends them, activating my cron job script. I will certainly have a read on cron jobs but before I do I wanted to make sure this is the right tool coz I am kinda short of time. So, the question is, is this going to be as user-friendly as I described above?

Comment: Cron jobs are a very good solution for your problem. They will run regardless of your Admin being logged in. The Admin will create mail records when submitting the form, and can simply log out. As the cron is running every x amount of time, it'll pick up those records and send mails accordingly. Cron jobs in general are an interesting thing to get some knowledge on, it allows for a lot of time-based automation (i.e. lazy emailing, expiries, cleanups, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much) I will get into reading about cron jobs right away)